# Toggle show/hide bug on Sliding Read More WP plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, show-hide, jquery

Hello Js newbie question.

I'm happily using Sliding Read More Wordpress plug-in (http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/sliding-read-more).

Everything works fine if you toggle to show / hide the same "read more".

But when you toggle one and then you toggle another without closing the previous one then there's mismatch on "Read More / Read Less" text.

You can see the bug live here: http://www.cntlsn.com/sandbox

Here is the code where all the magic happens

```
var $jslide = jQuery.noConflict();

$jslide(document).ready(function() {

    // initialise the visibility check
    var is_visible = false;

    // append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "toggle"
    $jslide('.toggle').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>');

    // hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
    $jslide('.toggle').hide();

    // capture clicks on the toggle links
    $jslide('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

        // switch visibility
        is_visible = !is_visible;

        // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
        $jslide(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);


        // toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
        //$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
        $jslide(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');


        // return false so any link destination is not followed
        return false;

    });
});
```

I've tried editing on my own with no result...
Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: Solved here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016721/show-hide-multiple-elements-independently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016721/show-hide-multiple-elements-independently)